Using Django session authentication with access token + refresh token?
I am currently developing a project using django rest framework. I want to integrate social account  log in like Google etc. This is working but the oauth2 response returns an access token, refresh token and id token which is a JWT. An example of the reponse is below. But for users who dont use social log in, they receive a session id cookie.
{
  "access_token": "ya29.a0AXooCgtlrshHEmZpGgjtAf--tHWg3R0XVHRvu8loe6lz6cAEAsI3PltGks71uBC5HJDb35sMkFcLKzOKW2en4Vr39ywt7YP9kMotXMxaTcrJyaZTC3xPuv9LlSCzsqrU2wgQTChmA7iyxmQH5XTT2BibhoyUFdxGSG0caCgYKATMSARISFQHGX2MiJk5x1uikM0e2q-nhXEBMnQ",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "refresh_token": "1//0gxxUoZyRFO9ECgYIARAAGBASNwF-L9IrGHliubMCOWomlmTTzSh4aKwmS1GeVoNmBB6-6VZ-a2MQAzoSzS3B-e_KL8NUyCh3",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "id_token": "jwt token"
}

So should I just use Django's default session auth together with the access_token and refresh token stored in cookies? Seems a bit complicated to keep track of all of these in cookie.
I tried searching around but cant seem to find much, any help would be greatly appreciated.
